# Cannot convert value of type "CGRect" to specified type "CGSize"

Tags: objective-c, swift

I'm trying to write some code, but I get the error in the title... here is the code...

```
let text: NSString = messages[indexPath.row] as! NSString
var size: CGSize = text.boundingRectWithSize(CGSizeMake(240.0, 480.0), options: NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesDeviceMetrics, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(14.0)], context: nil)
```

I get the error in the second line

Also, I have the Objective-C code, which is ok... But I'd like it in Swift

```
NSString *text = [messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
CGSize size = [text sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(240.0f, 480.0f) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
```

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Note, your Objective-C and Swift code are doing different things. In Swift you're calling `boundingRectWithSize` and in Objective-C you're calling `sizeWithFont`. If you're converting the Objective-C to Swift, you may want to call the `sizeWithFont` method in Swift as well.

Comment: I tried doing that with sizeWithFontn in swift, but it doesn't work... can you help me in that??

Comment: Hmm, apologies, `sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode:` was deprecated in iOS 7.0 and thus not included in Swift.

Comment: And... do you have some idea of how to solve it...??? Thanks

Comment: The answer below should work fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try adding `.size` to the end like:

```
var size:CGSize = text.boundingRectWithSize(CGSizeMake(240.0, 480.0), options: NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesDeviceMetrics, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(14.0)], context: nil).size
```